# Why are my bootsrap cards not uniform in length?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, row

I am doing a project that demands I format a particular responsive design with html bootstrap classes and although I have the format the way that I want it, I don't understand why in the desktop rendering of the page my cards in my rows are not the same width in pixels. Can anybody figure out what's going on? Here's the full html doc just in case the error is anywhere up top for some reason, though the section I'm referencing begins at the "!Bottom Section". I'm not allowed to write my own css code for this project so it's just the html. Thanks for the time guys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <title>All about bears</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="bg-info">
    <h1 class="pt-4 pl-5">All About Bears</h1>
    <p class="pb-4 pl-5">Read all about bears and what they're like.</p>
    <nav class="text-center mb-4 bg-light py-3">
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">About</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="pl-4">
    <!--Top Section-->
    <div class="row px-lg-5 col-sm">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/490/480"/>
      <section class="col px-lg-5 row-sm">
        <h2 class="text-center py-3 mb-3">Bears are neat!</h2>
      <p class="px-lg-5">Thejk jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf. djfid soox ejf jf dic ciciic deksj zjdklfdd. jsklddox jjifke sjzo.
        sdjidfox.
      </p>
      <p class="px-lg-5"> Ddod co e nfdklooox djfed sox dofdds f od poof fjso f  dfds. hejk didof sdjdof. dis
        sdidof dfjdsioxxoxodfd sjfo, eiw wod jjofdfdwo sdfo. jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf.
      </p>
      <p class="px-lg-5">Thejk jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf. jdkdfjoejfds fjef sdfjo sod qpd fjoxf feea dsj sdf. dsjods jofej djozfjox.
      </p>
      <a class="pl-lg-5 pt-4 mt-4 text-dark" href="#">Source</a>
      </section>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!--Bottom Section-->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <!--First Row-->
      <div class="row row-cols-6 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-around mb-4">
        <!--Card One-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/225"/>
          <p class="card-body">These bears are playing around</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Card Two-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/224"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear is looking off into the distance</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Second Row-->
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-6 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-around mb-4">
        <!--Card Three-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/223"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear just found some food</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Card Four-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/222"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear is one of our favorites</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here are some screenshots illustrating the difference in pixels:**

[Img-of-pixels1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbiB.jpg)
[Img-of-pixels2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd3HM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <title>All about bears</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="bg-info">
    <h1 class="pt-4 pl-5">All About Bears</h1>
    <p class="pb-4 pl-5">Read all about bears and what they're like.</p>
    <nav class="text-center mb-4 bg-light py-3">
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">About</a>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark px-3">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="pl-4">
    <!--Top Section-->
    <div class="row px-lg-5 col-sm">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/490/480"/>
      <section class="col px-lg-5 row-sm">
        <h2 class="text-center py-3 mb-3">Bears are neat!</h2>
      <p class="px-lg-5">Thejk jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf. djfid soox ejf jf dic ciciic deksj zjdklfdd. jsklddox jjifke sjzo.
        sdjidfox.
      </p>
      <p class="px-lg-5"> Ddod co e nfdklooox djfed sox dofdds f od poof fjso f  dfds. hejk didof sdjdof. dis
        sdidof dfjdsioxxoxodfd sjfo, eiw wod jjofdfdwo sdfo. jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf.
      </p>
      <p class="px-lg-5">Thejk jkee soodjkfd jkl djfedios nkjf de. fjkdosdjd ficklsldf ddfe. jjkldif jjf asope mekdox kididlwne df.
        asdjdfv ioejfdslkcj fdiolsmefjd klfdslkjdf. jdkdfjoejfds fjef sdfjo sod qpd fjoxf feea dsj sdf. dsjods jofej djozfjox.
      </p>
      <a class="pl-lg-5 pt-4 mt-4 text-dark" href="#">Source</a>
      </section>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!--Bottom Section-->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <!--First Row-->
      <div class="row col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-around mb-4">
        <!--Card One-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/225"/>
          <p class="card-body">These bears are playing around</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Card Two-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/224"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear is looking off into the distance</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Second Row-->
      </div>
      <div class="row col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-around mb-4">
        <!--Card Three-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/223"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear just found some food</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
        <!--Card Four-->
        <section class="col col-4 border card p-0 mx-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/225/222"/>
          <p class="card-body">This bear is one of our favorites</p>
          <button class="card-body bg-primary p-lg-2 m-2 rounded text-light">See more bears</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Replace row-cols-6 with col-md-6